# Resaltar una frase en un print Phyton3

Tags: python

Tengo una variable que almacena lo siguiente:

```
    configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line.  End with CNTL/Z.
PERIKO11(config)#hostname PERIKO11
PERIKO11(config)#
PERIKO11(config)#int eth0/0
PERIKO11(config-if)#
PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi
                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.

PERIKO11(config-if)#
PERIKO11(config-if)#exit
PERIKO11(config)#
PERIKO11(config)#line vty 5 10
PERIKO11(config-line)#
PERIKO11(config-line)#password 1234
PERIKO11(config-line)#
PERIKO11(config-line)#login
PERIKO11(config-line)#
PERIKO11(config-line)#loggin sync
PERIKO11(config-line)#
PERIKO11(config-line)#exit
PERIKO11(config)#end
PERIKO11#
```

¿Cómo podría hacer que, se imprimiese la variable y que destacase en rojo lo siguiente?:

```
PERIKO11(config-if)#asdfdsdescription holiwi
                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
```

Es decir, que encuentre el patrón "Invalid input detected at" y destaque en rojo el patrón encontrado y las 2 líneas de arriba.

Comment: ¿Esto quieres que suceda en la terminal?

Comment: Quiero que suceda en el print que devuelve Python en la terminal donde se ejecuta

Comment: Echale un ojo a la librería [colorama](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/)